# Elasticsearch 5 function score with filter doesn't work after upgrade

Tags: elasticsearch-5

I have upgraded Elasticsearch from version 2 to version 5. Now this query is not working any more..

```
GET _search {
  "query":{
  "function_score":{
    "functions":[{"field_value_factor":{"field":"popularity"}}],
    "score_mode":"multiply",

    "query":{
      "filtered":{
        "query":{"match_all":{}},
          "filter":{
          "bool":{
            "must":[{"term":{"image.colors.color":"red"}}]
           }
         }   
       }
    }
 }
```

I am getting:

```
no [query] registered for [filtered]
```

I have tried different options without `filtered` but still no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filtered-query.html - _"The filtered query is replaced by the bool query."_ …

Comment: @stuartd Thank You but I am still don't know how to rewrite this inside function score.